# Consulta a dos tablas sin repetir algunas columnas

Tags: mysql, select

### Tablas:

CREATE TABLE empleado ( 
codigo VARCHAR(8), 
PRIMARY KEY(codigo), 
nombreEmpleado VARCHAR(25), 
departamento VARCHAR(20), 
fechaNacimiento DATE, 
edad TINYINT(2) 
);

CREATE TABLE hijo ( 
codigo VARCHAR(8), # mismo código del empleado padre 
nombreHijo VARCHAR(25), 
fechaNacimiento DATE, 
edad TINYINT(2));

### Consulta:

SELECT H.codigo, nombreEmpleado, nombreHijo, H.fechaNacimiento, H.edad 
FROM empleado E, hijo H 
WHERE E.codigo = H.codigo 
ORDER BY codigo;

### Resultado:

| Código | Nombre Empleado | Nombre Hijo | Fecha Nacimiento | Edad |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A001 | Lisbet | Daniela | 20/04/2012 | 8 años |
| A001 | Lisbet | Belem | 26/12/2001 | 19 años |
| E001 | Ricardo | Carla | 04/11/2011 | 9 años |
| L001 | Luis | Valente | 03/11/2019 | 1 años |

### Resultado deseado:

| Código | Nombre Empleado | Nombre Hijo | Fecha Nacimiento | Edad |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A001 | Lisbet | Daniela | 20/04/2012 | 8 años |
|  |  | Belem | 26/12/2001 | 19 años |
| E001 | Ricardo | Carla | 04/11/2011 | 9 años |
| L001 | Luis | Valente | 03/11/2019 | 1 años |

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Eso no es sql estandard y ningun motor te va a mostrar datos asi.. Eso es un problema puro de presentacion...

Comment: Luego de tu edicion, la segunda tabla no es sql standar. SQL no entiende de presentacion y llena todas las columnas con datos. Asi que tu solucion sigue siendo la primera...

Comment: eso con SQL no tiene que ser resuelto, debe ser controlado en la vista.